# How to make two random generated integers divisible by each other in java?

Tags: java, android-studio, random, division

I am a newbie and trying to write a java code in my android studio project to generate two random integers up to 100(included) and what I am actually trying to do is to check if the first random integer is bigger than the second random integer and I also want to check if the first rand.num. is divisible by the second rand.num.

So far, I am able to generate two rand. nums in OnCreate method by using Math.random():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_division);

    randomFirstNum = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    randomSecondNum = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
```

and I am trying to write two functions.

The first function is to generate a question string depending on the rand. integer numbers. i.e.

```
    private void generateQuestion(int randomFirstNum, int randomSecondNum) {
        String firstNum = String.valueOf(randomFirstNum);
        String secondNum = String.valueOf(randomSecondNum);
        String question = null;
    
        if(randomFirstNum % randomSecondNum == 0 && randomFirstNum > randomSecondNum){
            question = firstNum + " ÷ " + secondNum + " = ?";
        } else if(randomSecondNum % randomFirstNum == 0 && randomSecondNum > randomFirstNum){
            question = secondNum + " ÷ " + firstNum + " = ?";
        }
    
        textViewQuestion.setText(question);
}
```

And the next function is to find the result of the division question. i.e.

```
private int findResult(int randomFirstNum, int randomSecondNum) {
    if (randomFirstNum > randomSecondNum && randomFirstNum % randomSecondNum == 0){
        return randomFirstNum / randomSecondNum;
    } else if {(randomSecondNum > randomFirstNum && randomSecondNum % randomFirstNum == 0)
        return randomSecondNum / randomFirstNum;
    }
}
```

I know the code is not right and there are missing parts, I am just stucked here. But I hope I was able to explain my issue a bit. I want to be able to generate a question where the first rand.integer will be either bigger than the second rand.integer or equal to the second rand.integer on the secreen ( i.e "20 ÷ 2 = ?" or "21 ÷ 7 = ?" or 11 ÷ 11 = ? - There might be a chance that two rand. integers are gonna be the same numbers :)

I am just stucked at the point of what to do if the both integers are odds (i.e. "17 ÷ 11 = ?" I don't want to end up with these kind of questions :)

I would appreciate a lot if someone can shad some light on my question and hopefully provide a clear answer for me! :) Thank you so much for sticking around and spend your time to read my question.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask for. If both the numbers are odd numbers you don't want to perform the division?

Comment: Why not have one of the random numbers be the answer to the division. Then you can multiply the two random numbers together to get the number to be divided.

Comment: For example I can't divide 17 ÷ 11 = ? and get an integer right? But I can divide 17 ÷ 17 = ? or 11 ÷ 11 = ? I will try to be more specific; I am trying to generate two random integers and these can be odds or evens. I want these random numbers divisible by each other (i.e. randNum1 % randNum2 == 0). I also would like to be able to generate a question where the bigger rand. integer is gonna be shown on the question the first i.e. 20 ÷ 2 = ? There might be a slight chance to come up with the same even or odd numbers so it is still acceptable to show a question like 11 ÷11 = ? or 4 ÷ 4 = ?

Comment: Hi Superman, you're maybe confused, but I'll send you on the right track. Stackoverflow is for asking question on programming issues you're facing, but it's not the idea to teach you programming itself. For that reason you should read a book or look up educational web content. If you're having issues on the mathematical background, there is a subdomain of Stackexchange on that too. Maybe you could focus your question around a specific programming issue you have. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Janos Vinceller. I was actually surprised about your comment at first because there are tons of questions here on Stackoverflow almost similar to mine. So that's why I posted my question because my issue was a bit different. I wasn't able to find a way to get to divisors of a random integer. There are also questions about programming issues of course as you said. I am a newbie (as I have mentioned before:) and I for sure read lots of educational web content and books so that I can learn more and more :) Thank you for your suggestion to check Stackexchange, will do that.

Comment: So, thanks to @Osama Abdul Rehman 's answer. I was able to assign two random integers and check the divisibility of the first random integer.

Comment: Your tile does not agree with your question. Please fix one of them so they agree.

Answer (score 1):

First number can be generated without any constraints, but to cater first number must be divisible by second number and first number >= second number requirement, you have a constraint that second number must be the divisor of first number as it will fulfil both requirements.

So you can generate first number from 1 to 100 and whatever that number is, find out its divisors and pick a random divisor from the divisors list.

```
private static void generateQuestion() {
       int first = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
       List<Integer> firstNumDivisors = getDivisors(first);
       
       int divisorsRandIndex = (int) (Math.random() * firstNumDivisors.size());
       int second = firstNumDivisors.get(divisorsRandIndex);

    System.out.println(first + " " + second);
    // Create your question from first and second numbers here
}

private static List<Integer> getDivisors(int number) {
    List<Integer> divisors = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=1;i<=number;i++) 
        if (number%i==0) 
            divisors.add(i);
            
    return divisors;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help but...

Create a function that displays your question and if you want your first operand to produce higher `int` than the 2nd and make sure numbers are divisible to each other, you can use this?

```
function displayDivisionQuestion(operand1, operand2) {
    operand1 = operand1 * operand2;

    document.getElementById("operand1").textContent = operand1 > operand2 ? operand1 : operand2;
    document.getElementById("operand2").textContent = operand1 > operand2 ? operand2 : operand1;
    document.getElementById('operator').textContent = "/";
}
```

Comment: Your answer is in JavaScript, not Java